# ASP.NET static content always caches

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project that uses ASP.NET MVC 5 and angular.js
Recently (though I'm not sure when) changes to my angular.js views are not being reflected in the browser.
When I look at the developer tools in Chrome, it indicates that it is pulling it directly from cache. The Last-Modified header appears to be a couple days old and the ASP.NET server is returning 304 Not Modified for the html file.

Does anyone have any clue why my static content (specifically html files) are being cached by the browser when there *are* in fact changes.

**What I have tried:**

I have modified the Web.config like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <caching enabled="false" />
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

However, that doesn't seem to make any difference.
I have also checked that the file system is recognizing my changes; the "date modified" on the files are much more recent than the "last-modified" being returned by the server.

Comment: Since it is already cached by your browser, you may need to clear the browser's cache before disabling the cache in the config will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Try this on code behind

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago and this actually worked for me.

Comment: I don't have any code-behind... The html page is being served up directly by asp.net.

Comment: oops i read it wrongly. I thought you have a traditional as.netapplication